# HTML drag browser from Visual Studio won't work

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, drag-and-drop

[image: Issue drag html]

I used to drag my html file from Visual Studio Code to the browser and it worked, but now it won't let me, as I get a "not allowed" on my cursor when I drag it to the browser and it doesn't open it.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting way to open an HTML file.

In my opinion the best solution for that is to download the "Live Server extension" (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)

Live server extension will allow you to see your change without refresching your web page.

It's easy to use, you just need to click on the button "Go live" that will appear on the bottom right side of VSCode after installed the extension.

An other solution is to open directly the HTML file that you're working on but you'll need to refresh your web page after every changes.

Comment: Yeah, I also use that (now I don't have an alternative but to use it). But I liked the other way best and I don't know why it doesn't work anymore